# require_once and include are having php.ini issues

Tags: php, require

Hi I am getting this error, when I run the index.php file which includes

```
require_once("system/config.php");
```

I am wondering what does this message mean, and how do I go about fixing such an issue. As this site worked fine when I ran it directly on my Mac.

```
 require_once(): Failed opening required 'system/core.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
```

**ALL THE BELOW ANSWERS ARE CORRECT!** 
However my issue was a CHMOD issue I had 644 instead of 744

Comment: The path/file doesn't exist so it tried to look in your default include path. Double check the path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means you're trying to include the file with an incorrect path. What happens when you try the full path?

```
require_once(getcwd() . 'system/config.php');
```

The way your script is now, it's looking for the file with a directory structure like this:

```
file.php        <- is calling the require_once()
- system        <- the system directory
  - config.php  <- the config file
```

But this isn't the path where it's located.

Comment: Correct, But see above - I award it to you, because of the detailed answer you gave. However My issue was a CHMOD error

Answer (score 1):

The file `system/core.php` needs to be relatively to the file which is declaring the line `require_once("system/core.php");` (that's `system/config.php`) or the direcory that contains `system` must be in your [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). Search for `core.php` on your Mac. Check the configuration settings (`include_path`) on your Mac.

Comment: Correct as well, see above.